# How would I fix this issue; Imports System.Security.Cryptography will not function with Imports System.Net

Tags: vb.net, import, cryptography, system

I am making a program in VB.Net which requires the imports of four import thingamajiggys. However, `Imports System.Security.Cryptography` will not work alongside each other imports.

I've tried arranging the order they work in. `Imports System.Security.Cryptography` will not work at all with `Systems.Net`, but it will work alongside `Imports System.Text` and `Imports System.IO`

```vb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text



Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Function SHA1(ByVal Content As String) As String
        Dim Molecule As New Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim bytestring() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Content)
        bytestring = Molecule.ComputeHash(bytestring)
        Dim finalstring As String = Nothing
        For Each bt As Byte In bytestring
            finalstring &= bt.ToString("x2")
        Next
        Return finalstring
    End Function
```

A red wiggled line (like the spelling mistake in Word) appears under `Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` but only when `Systems.Net` has been imported. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the red wiggly line because System.Net also has a 'Security' namespace and it's trying to find Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider in there. 
To fix it either type

```
Dim Molecule As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
```

or

```
Dim Molecule As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aliases.

```
Imports CryptoSecurity = System.Security
Imports MyNet = System.Net
```

Then in code

```
    Dim Molecule As New CryptoSecurity.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
```

You can use any names that make sense to you for the alias.